# A spanning set that is not linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

What is an example of a spanning set that is not a linearly independent set?
I'm having trouble trying to figure it out.

Comment: For any vector space, the space itself is a spanning set and is never linearly independent (e.g., because it contains 0$)

Comment: Take a spanning set that is linearly independent, add a dependent element into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just take any basis, and add one redundant vector to it, such as the zero vector, or a linear multiple of a vector already in your set, or a linear combination of vectors already in your set. In any of these cases (the first being a special case of the second, which is a special case of the third), if you start with a spanning set, you end up with a spanning set with a dependence relation, i.e., one that is not linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the whole space always works because it has $0$.

Comment: Thanks very much, its clear to me now